# Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: '.3-1' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I'm gonna update this class' html but I keep getting the same error and have absolutely no idea why

`` document.querySelector(`.${clickField}`).innerHTML = `<img src ='${icon}.svg'>` ``

> Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: '.3-1' is not a valid selector

(I've seen similar questions but they all have jquery etc so i didnt understand shit from them)

Someone just said classes cant start w numbers he's right im so dumb lmfao
[image of 3-1 existing in DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O4H8.png)

Comment: What that is saying is that the contents of `clickField` is `3-1` and it can't find that anywhere in the dom as classes can't start with a digit.

Comment: What is `clickField` supposed to be?

Comment: Most likely an issue that the class name you are trying to use starts with a numerical

Comment: @imvain2 classes *can* start with a digit but the values must be properly escaped in CSS selector strings

Comment: Just try a class name that does not start with number first

Comment: @D.Pardal 3-1, the result coming from there is correct is probably happening because classes cant start with numbers i completely forgot about that

Comment: @Pointy how do i do that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4f5zL7ko/1/  Query selector errors on the starting with a number.  The explicit class lookup doesn't care.

Comment: @Huangism yep got it

Comment: @AseLast `document.querySelector(".\\0033-1")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `clickField` is supposed to be the class of the element you want to get. In that case, since the class starts with a digit, the easiest way to select it using CSS selector is using attribute selectors, like so:

```js
document.querySelector(`[class="${clickField}"]`).innerHTML = `<img src ='${icon}.svg'>`
```

If `clickField` might contain `"` characters, you need to replace `${clickField}` by `${clickField.replace(/"/g, '\\"')}` to escape them properly.

There is also a far easier way, using `document.getElementsByClassName()`:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName(clickField)[0].innerHTML = `<img src ='${icon}.svg'>`
```

Classes may contain any characters except space, as the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#classes) imposes no restrictions on them.

Comment: still getting the same error, just found the fix though